# Updating changes in database(postgresql) to remote backup database

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, backup

I have created a postgresql database backup on AWS Linux using pg_dump . Now i want to commit only the changes made in the database after the backup to the backup database without having to pd_dump the entire database , so as to maintain consistency.

Is there a way to commit only the changes and not the entire database / table. Also if there isn't a solution then is there any other alternative i could use to address the problem at hand. I'm using postgresql v 9.5. Are there any third party software that i could use ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: in MySQL we have binlogs which can be used. I am sure there should be something similar in postgresql

Comment: Thanks Deepak . Solved the problem using pgbarman tool .

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Prashant; this could be achieved using pgbarman tool.

Comment: After following the tutorial : https://www.systemcodegeeks.com/databases/postgresql/postgresql-backup-restore-migration/ , i'm stuck on step three where i've to copy ssh key to the postgres user on another server(ssh-copy-id postgres@ip). The command prompts me to enter password  for postgres user , which i was never asked to set during installation. How can i bypass this problem ?  Help will be much appreciated